# Formatting multiple props in react-native stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formatting

I am trying to find the best practices for formatting a stateless component which has multiple props. I understand that the norm is to do the following:

```
const myItem = ({myProp, AnotherProp}) => {

}
```

I would like to understand how best to approach this when the number of props means the length of line containing myItem would mean it extends 80 characters. I have looked at style guides such as the Air BnB React guide and also their Javascript guide, but still I haven't found the correct approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact way you might be looking for is this:

```
const myItem = (props) => {
   const { myProp,AnotherProp } = props  
   console.log('all props extracted', myProp,AnotherProp) 
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Is this destructuring assignment of ES6 ?